# Find All Nodeselectors in a Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, redhat, kubernetes-nodeport, nodeselector

I have a big cluster on Openshift Platform. I want to find all the projects or pods that are using NodeSelector. Is there a command for that? How can I make a list of all the projects with NodeSelectors?

I have a command for listing all the services using nodeport. But I could not do it for nodeSelector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jq for that:

```bash
$ kubectl get pod -A -o json \
  | jq -r '.items[] | select(.spec.nodeSelector != null) | .metadata.namespace + "/" + .metadata.name + ", " + (.spec.nodeSelector | tostring)'
```

will return something like

```bash
<namespace>/<podname>, {"key": "value"}
```

for all pods that are using a node selector.

Comment: This works great. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer was helpful please consider accepting it by clicking the check symbol below to the voting buttons. Thanks!